# Efficient computation of ridge/lasso regression

Tags: lasso, ridge-regression

n the book "Introduction to Statistical learning with R" https://hastie.su.domains/ISLR2/ISLRv2_website.pdf ,

authors say on page 247 -

"There are very efficient algorithms for fitting both ridge and lasso models; in both cases the entire coefficient paths can be computed with about the same amount of work as a single least squares fit"

Can someone tell me how the algorithm works? As in, how can we do computations for several values of λ at about the computational cost for one λ?

Comment: They key with lasso in particular is that for almost all times, $\hat{\beta}$ actually changes in a predictable way, and it's possible to calculate when this changes. That algorithm is called Least Angle Regression https://tibshirani.su.domains/ftp/lars.pdf Ridge regression, on the other hand, I don't know off the top of my head how to efficiently compute a trajectory for; solving it for a given $\lambda$ is very very similar to solving the OLS problem.

Comment: @Ben Oh that's fascinating, do you have a reference you can share?

Comment: @Ben Been looking at the docs, isn't this kind of apples and oranges, as glmnet is describing *generalized* linear models, whereas LARS is an algorithm for least-squares error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138783/discussion-between-john-madden-and-ben).